# value subtract is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark Scala while trying to use subtract method, I get the following error

```
<console>:29: error: value subtract is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

But from the following links I can see it is present in Python though

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/7505/comparing-two-dataframes.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract

Do we have subtract method at all in of Spark Scala? If not what is the replacement for it?

My sample code looks like this:

```scala
scala> val myDf1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,2)).toDF
myDf1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> val myDf2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2)).toDF
myDf2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> val result = myDf1.subtract(myDf2)
<console>:28: error: value subtract is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
       val result = myDf1.subtract(myDf2)
```

Comment: What version of spark are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `subtract` doesn't exist and honestly I'm not sure about what you are trying to do :

```
scala> val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,2)).toDF
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2)).toDF
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df1.except(df2).show
+-----+                                                                         
|value|
+-----+
+-----+
```

But it seems like you want to find those duplicates and keep them instead of removing them.

From the top of my head :

```
scala> val dupes = df1.groupBy("value").count.filter("count > 1").drop("count")
dupes: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> dupes.show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    2|
+-----+
```

Comment: I am trying to find the id(s) that are duplicate in another DataFrame. In this case df1 is having duplicate id 2. Do we any shortcut to find out?

Comment: You haven't answered my question.

Comment: I'm using Spark 2.x

Comment: You want to drop those duplicate ? Why do you want to use them ?

Comment: I want to find those duplicates and log into some file. That's it.